# rowid in SQLITE3 and Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rowid

I perform an insert on a database and I want to know what the rowid is for that insert.

Does this accomplish the task:

```
Uri uri = ContentResolver.insert(url,values);    //Make insert
int rowid= Integer.parseInt(uri.getFragment());  //Get rowid
```

The Android documentation states that the `insert` returns "the URL of the newly created row."  And the Uri method `getFragment()` is supposed to return everything after the /#.  So, is my understanding correct that `getFragment()` would thus return to me the rowid?

Answer (score 6):

To parse the URI after an insert and get the id you should use `ContentUris.parseId(uri)`.

Comment: This provides me the rowid of the last inserted row?

Comment: How is this function any different from my code?  The insert statement returns a Uri of the row and from that I call getFragment to extract out the id.  In the Uri, after the "/#" would be all numeric - the rowid, no?